# how to format JS object with Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, underscore.js, lodash

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

org_data = [{ item: 'TESTING123', date: '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z' },{ item: 'TESTING456', date: '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z' }]

function formating (rows, key='date') {

  return _.chain(rows).keyBy('item').mapValues(key).value()
};

// output
{
 TESTING123: 2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z,
 TESTING456: 2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z,
}

//expected output
{
 'TESTING123' : '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z',
 'TESTING456': '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z',
}
```

Actually data is get by SQL query and item (`models.TextField()`) and date (`models.DateTimeField()`) in a django backend
It seem that the JS object is broken , I wonder any solution for this case

Comment: var result = formating(org_data)

var str = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) { 
  return "" + key + "=" + result[key];
})

Comment: why + "="? the result turn to be [ 'undefined=2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z' ]

Comment: It give  ["TESTING123=2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z", "TESTING456=2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z"] not undefined

Comment: can you check my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var org_data = [
  { item: 'TESTING123', date: '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { item: 'TESTING456', date: '2020-0610T00:00:00.000Z' }
]

function formating (rows, key = 'date') {
  return _.chain(rows)
    .keyBy('item')
    .mapValues(key)
    .value()
}
var t = formating(org_data)

var str = Object.keys(t).map(function (key) {
  return '' + key + '=' + t[key]
})

console.log(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```